# Installation aborted twice

Tags: settings, boot, system

I have win-11
and I have installed 10s of different Linux versions (debian, ubuntu, xubuntu, zorinOs, ......)
all without any problems, But the new Version of "elementary os 6 odin" today failed twice.
(after I had my partition ready for installing)
it was something: installation not possible, try it again, or restart....

before on Bios I have disabled UEFI

https://ibb.co/jGhF063   (german installation)

Answer (score 0):

can you show us the output of the terminal content when click on the "Details" button once you reached that state?

I had the same issue and at the end it turned out, that I had to format my whole disk from a DOS partition table to a GPT partition table.
In my case this was no problem as I was OK with deleting all data on that HD.

Cheers, Michael